# $http using a rest Controller in Angular 1.4.8

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm recently new in AngularJS and I'm trying to use an alias on my `controller` to call the data that is comming from a `$http` response `factory`.

What I've done right now is what it follows:

**DiscoverService.js**

```
var discoverService = angular.module('discover.services', []);

discoverService.factory('discoverV', function ($http) {
  return {
    list: function(callback){
      $http.get('https://myurl.com/get/jsondata').success(callback);
    }
  };
});
```

**DiscoverCtrl.js**

```
var discoverModule = angular.module('discover', ['discover.services']);

discoverModule.controller('discoverCtrl', [ '$scope', 'discoverV', function($scope, discoverV) {
  $scope.elm = [];

  discoverV.list(function(data) {
    $scope.elm = data;
  });
}]);
```

**_discover.html**

```
<div class="wrapper" ng-controller="discoverCtrl as discover">
  <article>
    <section id="block-stories" class="container" ng-repeat="element in elm">
      {{element.story_id}}
    </section>
  </article>
</div>
```

I've been trying to do it and I don't understand why the next code doesn't work:

```
discoverModule.controller('discoverCtrl', [ 'discoverV', function(discoverV) {
  var elm = this;
  elm.videos = [];

  discoverV.list(function(data) {
    elm.videos = data;
  });

}]);

<div class="wrapper" ng-controller="discoverCtrl as discover">
  <article>
    <section id="block-stories" class="container" ng-repeat="element in discover.videos">
      {{element.story_id}}
    </section>
  </article>
</div>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: What doesn't work? Currently I don't see a `discoverVideos` service for you to inject which could be an issue.

Comment: I updated my answer because I was using some old code with the new HTML @MatthewGreen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you wrote `discoverCtrl as discover` you should use `discover` to access to the controller scope.

So, you should wrote something like:

```
<div class="wrapper" ng-controller="discoverCtrl as discover">
  <article>
    <section id="block-stories" class="container" ng-repeat="element in discover.videos">
      {{element.story_id}}
    </section>
  </article>
</div>
```

I created an example ([link](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3504/)) where I just mocked `$http` call and it works (only if you got another error).

Hope it will help.

Comment: I just realiced I commit a mistake once again! I have updated the code with that fixed, thanks. The question still keeps and is how could I do the same with an alias instead of $scope.

Comment: You already did it. you wrote `var elm = this;` in controller scope `this` is an alias of controller. When you use `controller as ctrl` feature, `ctrl` will be the same as `this` inside controller.

Comment: Finally I got this, Thanks!